# Entropy due to linearization of Freely-Jointed Chain

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, polymers

Say I model a polymer as a freely jointed chain in 3D with N bonds of length L each one. If I stretch the chain (initially coiled) along a 2D surface until it becomes linear (basically a 1D line of length N*L), is there any way to estimate the change in entropy?

Comment: If I understand your question, since the entropy of the final state would be zero (since there is only a single way of arranging your polymer in a straight line), are you asking what is the entropy of the initial state?

Comment: Yes, is it Eq. (2) from this answer?
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/378884/understanding-roles-of-energy-and-entropy-in-different-polymer-models/378904#378904

Comment: yes, pretty much